# Plot with marked extremum and saddle point if any in wave velocity as a function of wave number

Tags: plotting

I have the following 5th degree Polynomial Equation in **complex wave velocity** w(tauT, tauq) as a function of real parameters taoT and tauq:

```
eqn = (1 + (c2^2/c1^2)*w^2)*(1 + k*taoT*c2*w + (c2*d/k)*w*(1 + k*tauq*c2*w + (1/2)*k^2*tauq^2*c2^2*w^2)) + (e*c2*d/k)*w*(1 + k*tauq*c2*w + (1/2)*k^2*tauq^2*c2^2*w^2) == 0;
```

The parameters are given as:

```
c1=4631.0; c2=2280.1; d=8066.8; e=0.0168; k=1;
```

The range for both of taoT and Taoq is:

```
[10^-10, 10^-1]
```

Some authors' have plotted the following graphs from the above equations. I don't know Mathematica very well but need some help for my research.
[image]

Also, **marked the extremum values and points** if possible on both the graphs.
Can anyone please help me for plotting like above two figures? I am in basic level in learning Mathematica 11.0. Seeking kind help!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
c1 = 4631.0; c2 = 2280.1; d = 8066.8; e = 0.0168; k = 1;
eqn = (1 + (c2^2/c1^2)*w^2)*(1 + 
      k*taoT*c2*w + (c2*d/k)*
       w*(1 + k*tauq*c2*w + (1/2)*k^2*tauq^2*c2^2*w^2)) + (e*c2*d/k)*
    w*(1 + k*tauq*c2*w + (1/2)*k^2*tauq^2*c2^2*w^2) == 0

(*  309004. w (1 + 2280.1 tauq w + 2.59943*10^6 tauq^2 w^2) + (1 + 
     0.242414 w^2) (1 + 2280.1 taoT w + 
     1.83931*10^7 w (1 + 2280.1 tauq w + 2.59943*10^6 tauq^2 w^2)) == 
 0  *)
```

The solve it:

```
nsl = NSolve[eqn, w];
```

It returns 5 solutions. The 4th and 5th one can plot. The plots are equal in this case:

```
Plot3D[Log[10, 
  Re[w] /. nsl[[4, 1]] /. {taoT -> 10^t, 
    tauq -> 10^q}], {t, -10, -1}, {q, -10, -1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["lg(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(τ\), \(t\)]\))", 
    16], Style["lg(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(τ\), \(q\)]\))", 16], 
   Style["lg(w)", 16]}, PlotPoints -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

returning the following plot:

[image]

Further, the plot of the cross-section at taoT=10^-4:

```
LogLogPlot[
 Re[w] /. nsl[[4, 1]] /. taoT -> 10^-4, {tauq, 10^-10, 10^-1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 20, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(τ\), \(t\)]\)", 16], 
   Style["w", 16]}]
```

yielding this:

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

### First plot

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
c1 = 4631.0; c2 = 2280.1; d = 8066.8; e = 0.0168; k = 1;
eqn = (1 + (c2^2/c1^2)*w^2)*(1 + 
      k*taoT*c2*w + (c2*d/k)*
       w*(1 + k*tauq*c2*w + (1/2)*k^2*tauq^2*c2^2*w^2)) + (e*c2*d/k)*
    w*(1 + k*tauq*c2*w + (1/2)*k^2*tauq^2*c2^2*w^2) == 0;
sol=NSolveValues[eqn,w];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  Plot[Re@sol[[2]]/.taoT->10^-1,{tauq,10^-10,10^-1},
     ScalingFunctions->{"Log",Identity},PerformanceGoal->"Quality"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Second plot

```
Plot3D[Re@sol[[4]],{tauq,10^-10,10^-1},{taoT,10^-10,10^-1},
 ScalingFunctions->{"Log","Log",Identity},
 Mesh->10,PlotTheme->"Classic"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nasser Sir, I am grateful to you for such an wonderful code! Could you please tell me which version of Mathematica you are using because I'm using version 11.0 and when I run this code in my PC, it shows blank!

Comment: @NantuSarkar I am using V 13.3.1 on windows 10. Here is link to the [notebook](https://12000.org/tmp/10062023/notebook.nb)

Comment: Sir What should I do to run it using V 11.0 on Windows 7?

Comment: @NantuSarkar If the above code does not run the same on V 11, then I am afraid I can't help, as I use V 13.3.1. May be someone will have an idea where it does not work on V 11.

Comment: Nasser Sir, when I run the code from your notebook, I got empty figure! Could you please resolved the issue?It would be great help for me sir!I run other program (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275780/plotting-the-solution/275782#275782) of you and get nice figure sir. So, V 11.0 is not the problem I think.

Comment: @NantuSarkar `NSolveValues` was introduced in v12.3. Try `sol2 = NSolve[eqn, w]; Plot[Re@w /. sol2[[2]] /. taoT -> 10^-1, {tauq, 10^-10, 10^-1}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", Identity}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]; Plot3D[Re@w /. sol2[[4]], {tauq, 10^-10, 10^-1}, {taoT, 10^-10, 
  10^-1}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", Identity}, Mesh -> 10, 
 PlotTheme -> "Classic"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Format[tau[x_]] := Subscript[τ, x]

eqn = (1 + (c2^2/c1^2)*w^2)*(1 + 
       k*tau[T]*c2*w + (c2*d/k)*
        w*(1 + k*tau[q]*c2*w + (1/2)*k^2*tau[q]^2*c2^2*w^2)) + (e*c2*
       d/k)*w*(1 + k*tau[q]*c2*w + (1/2)*k^2*tau[q]^2*c2^2*w^2) == 0;

c1 = 4631; c2 = 22801/10; d = 80668/10; e = 168*^-4; k = 1;

roots = Solve[eqn, w];

n = Length@roots;
```

Plotting,

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{min, max, ptMin, ptMax},
  {min, max} = #[{func[w /. roots[[r]]] /.
        {tau[T] -> 10^logtT, tau[q] -> 10^x},
       -10 < x < -1}, x, WorkingPrecision -> 20] & /@
    {NArgMin, NArgMax};
  ptMin = {min, func[w /. roots[[r]]] /.
     {tau[T] -> 10^logtT, tau[q] -> 10^min}};
  ptMax = {max, func[w /. roots[[r]]] /.
     {tau[T] -> 10^logtT, tau[q] -> 10^max}};
  Show[Plot[
    func[w /. roots[[r]]] /. {tau[T] -> 10^logtT, 
      tau[q] -> 10^logtq},
    {logtq, -10, -1},
    PlotRange -> All,
    AxesOrigin -> {-10, 0},
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, True}},
    FrameTicks -> {{All, False}, {False, All}},
    FrameLabel -> {
      {StringForm["``(``)", func, Subscript[w, r]], None},
      {None, Log[tau[q]]}},
    WorkingPrecision -> 20,
    PlotPoints -> 50,
    MaxRecursion -> 5,
    ImageSize -> Medium],
   ListPlot[{{Callout[ptMin, NumberForm[ptMin, {5, 2}],
       Background -> Opacity[0]]},
     {Callout[ptMax, NumberForm[ptMax, {5, 2}],
       Below,
       Background -> Opacity[0]]}},
    PlotStyle -> Red,
    PlotMarkers -> {Style[▼, 14], 
      Style[▲, 14]}],
   PlotRangeClipping -> False,
   ImageSize -> Medium]],
 Row[{
   Control[{{func, Re, "function"}, {Re, Im, Abs},
     ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}],
   Spacer[50],
   Control[{{r, 2, "root"}, Range[n],
     ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}]}],
 Delimiter,
 {{logtT, -1, TraditionalForm[Log[tau[T]]]}, -10, -1, 0.05, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {func, r, logtT}]
```

[image]

In the second plot, the `PlotRange` is restricted. The plot that you showed is clipped even more -- both top and bottom.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{argMin, argMax, ptMin, ptMax},
  {argMin, argMax} = #[{func[w /. roots[[r]]] /.
         {tau[q] -> 10^x, tau[T] -> 10^y},
        -10 <= x <= -1, -10 <= y <= -1}, {x, y},
       WorkingPrecision -> 20][[-1]] & /@
    {NMinimize, NMaximize};
  {ptMin, ptMax} = ({-x, -y, func[w /. roots[[r]]] /.
         {tau[q] -> 10^x, tau[T] -> 10^y}} /. #) & /@
    {argMin, argMax};
  Show[
   Plot3D @@
    {func[w /. roots[[r]] /.
       {tau[T] -> 10^logtT, tau[q] -> 10^logtq}],
     {logtq, -10, -1}, {logtT, -10, -1},
     AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Blue] & /@
        {Log[tau[q]], Log[tau[T]], ""}),
     If[pltRng,
      PlotRange -> All,
      PlotRange -> Automatic],
     ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", "Reverse"},
     WorkingPrecision -> 20,
     PlotPoints -> 50,
     MaxRecursion -> 5,
     ImageSize -> Medium,
     SphericalRegion -> True},
   Legended[
    Graphics3D[{Red,
      Text[Style[▲, 14], ptMax],
      Text[Style[▼, 14], ptMin]}],
    PointLegend[{Red, Red}, {
      StringForm["Max\n``", NumberForm[ptMax, {5, 2}]],
      StringForm["Min\n``", NumberForm[ptMin, {5, 2}]]},
     LegendMarkers -> {Style[▲, 14], 
       Style[▼, 14]}]]]],
 Row[
  {Control[
    {{func, Re, "function"}, {Re, Im, Abs},
     ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}],
   Spacer[20],
   Control[
    {{r, 4, "root"}, Range[n],
     ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}],
   Spacer[20],
   Control[{{pltRng, False, "Plot\nRange"}, {True -> "All", 
      False -> "Clipped"},
     ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}]}],
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {func, r, pltRng}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir for nice code. Unfortunately I have V11 that is why I couldn't be able to run the code on my PC! Anyway I will be grateful to you for your kind help!